# I am getting the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'debias' on doing pickle.load()

Tags: python, pickle

I am using the following code to load a pickle file:

```
import pickle
fl = open('picklefilename.p','rb')
pfl = pickle.load(fl)
```

But I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shikhar/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    pfl = pickle.load(fl)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'debias'
```

I did `pip3 install debias` but I still get the above error. I am using Python 3.10.12

Comment: The error message says it is from line 1 of your code, however that does not seem to match line 1 of the code you posted.  Are you sure this is your real code?

Comment: How did you run this code? If you ran the python shell from the command line, (lets say you just ran `python3`), you could do `python3 -m pip show debias`. That would test whether your python3 and pip3 are in fact using the same python distribution.

Comment: @JohnGordon, thanks for pointing. Actually, I copy pasted the error from the terminal. As you correctly pointed out the error is indeed from the 3rd line.

Comment: @tdelaney, on doing `python3 -m pip show debias` I get ```Name: debias
Version: 0.165
Summary: remove bias from GAF files
Home-page: https://github.com/Rinoahu/debias
Author: xiao hu
Author-email: xiaohu@iastate.edu
License: GPLv3
Location: /home/shikhar/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages
Requires: Biopython, matplotlib, networkx, numpy, xlsxwriter
Required-by: 
```

Comment: If you add `import debias` as the first line, does it fail on that first line? It seems like you have more than one python environment. Maybe multiple pythons for instance in a jupyter notebook - maybe a python virtual envionment where you installed in one environment and ran in another.

Comment: In that same file, you could add `import site` and then `print(site.getsitepackages())` to see if `/home/shikhar/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages` is in the list. If so, I'm out of options!

Comment: Just tried `import debias`. As you guessed it failed at this statement with the same error message. How to rectify this?

Comment: I'm guessing that you have several different installations of python on your system.  Show us the output of this code `import sys; print(sys.path)`

Comment: `print(site.getsitepackages())` gives `['/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.10/dist-packages']`

Comment: print(sys.path) gives `['/home/shikhar', '/usr/lib/python310.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.10', '/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload', '/home/shikhar/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']`

Comment: Okay, those are two different outputs.  Which is correct?

Comment: I'm not sure why `'/home/shikhar/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages'` isn't in `getsitepackages`. But its in sys.path, so the package should resolve. I guess you check whether `/home/shikhar/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/debias` exists from the command line. But it should be there. I'm at a loss.

Comment: I have a `debias-0.165.dist-info`

Comment: This may not be the debias you are looking for. I ran your pip install and got a package that is... odd? evil? Maybe. It installs itself as package `lib` (so you do `lib.debias` (but who makes a package "lib"??). It hasn't been updated for 6 years and uses the old obsolete python EGG distribution format. You have a pickle expecting a top level package "debias" and there are a lot of debias-adjacent packages on pypi. Maybe you want one of the other ones? Bascilly, goto whereever you got the pickle file from and find out which debias package they use.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I will follow your suggestion and answer accordingly.